# How is the router configuration gui designed and implemented?

Tags: web, websites

It's a rather simple concept, and each vendor seems to have their own "Website" for their config. I am curious to find out a few things. In my linksys router, if I go to 192.168.1.1, it asks for a simple log in, followed by the status page.

Here ports/passwords and all that can be completely changed. What's interesting is how the firmware updater works. You can click upload, drop in their new firmware, and it presumably flashes the device.

What technologies / frameworks would be ideal for creating my own custom router page? I've seen a custom one ([Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato)).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network router firmware, not programming.

Comment: I am interested in understanding how they made the website interface. What methodology / frameworks they may have used...

Comment: You're missing the question entirely. I am not asking how to flash the firmware, but how the web interface was created. An answer below suggests a simple http server with static html pages.

Comment: This is off topic as you are asking about an implementation specific issue. [Programmers.SE On Topic Help Page](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a custom router page is no different than creating any other web page.  You use the tools that are most appropriate for that.

The real difference is that a UI for a router or other embedded device is going to be *much simpler.*  You're not going to be using elaborate frameworks like Ruby on Rails, Angular or even jQuery.  All you really need is probably some static HTML files and a simple HTTP server.

**Further Reading**
[Embedded Web Servers](http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/10/10/web-servers-for-embedded-systems/)

Comment: That makes sense, grab a simple web server. Put together some static html. Is it possible to execute scripts on the server after a file uploads? That's probably what the firmware uploader does.

Comment: While it may or may not be common for a router to use angular or jquery, it actually would be very logical for them to when you consider those libs make it much easier for them to write the whole thing with static content, they would make it easier for the devs to avoid constructing HTML in the firmware, rather just making the firmware have simple text responses that the static angular/jquery files render on the client.

Comment: @user791953: There is some kind of firmware update script that executes, yes.  I don't know exactly how it works, but I suspect that it is a simple file transfer of some sort from the computer to the router.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa In practice, I really doubt that any router manufacturer uses Javascript libraries of any kind. Router configuration pages need to work everywhere, without exception, even on machines still running IE6 with Javascript turned off.